# Powershell to CSV compare

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

Hello I'm trying to use some code I found on here to compare a CSV with Active Directory. I have a csv file with a list of users. I want to check this file and see if anything in the "Email" column from the spreadsheet matches an email address from AD. If it does, I want to list that email address and include the Canonical Name from AD so I can easily see what OU the user account is in.

This is what I'm working with:

```
$path = "C:\Scripts\Import.csv"
$outpath = "C:\Scripts\Export.csv"
$csv = Import-Csv $path 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory


foreach ($line in $csv) 
{
    $User = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($line.Email)))"  -Properties CanonicalName
    If ($User -ne $Null) {"User does exist in OU" + $line.Email + $User.CanonicalName}
    Else {"User not found in AD OU  - " + $line.Email} 
}
```

I've been able to modify this to suit my needs but I'm having some trouble piping the results out to a CSV file. Running the script as it's shown above outputs what I want to the screen but I'd like to have it in a CSV format. If I do something like:

```
$Results = foreach ($line in $csv)
```

and then use

```
$Results | export-CSV $outpath -NotypeInformation
```

I get the csv created but it just includes a the string value, header for Length and then a numeric value for each line. I can use Out-File to send the results to a txt file, which includes the same results that were displayed on the screen, but I'd really like this to be a csv, not txt file. I believe I need to reference the properties of the csv file and AD in order to build these into my export file but I'm having trouble doing that as I'm not sure how to build in the status of whether the user was found or not.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

**UPDATE - Final code**
This is the final code I went with.  This compares the users in the csv with AD users in the parent and child domain. It uses the email address field to match the users. It grabs the Canonical Name so I can see the OU the user is in and if the user is not found, it reports that in the Canonical Name field.

```
$path = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\InFile.csv"
$outpath = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\OutFile.csv"

# Importing CSV file 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Import-Csv $path |


ForEach-Object {
     Write-Progress -Activity "Comparing Imported File to Active Directory" -Status "Processing $($_.Email)" 

# Comparing CSV file to Domain.com users
If (
    $Value1 = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($_.Email)))" -server Domain.com -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName)
     {$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CanonicalName -Value $value1 -PassThru}

# Comparing CSV file to child.Domain.com users
ElseIF (     
    $Value2 = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($_.Email)))" -server child.Domain.com-Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName)
    {$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CanonicalName -Value $value2 -PassThru}

# Writing output for users not found in either domain
Else {$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CanonicalName -Value "Email Address not found in Active Directory" -PassThru}

#Exporting to CSV file


        New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject -Property @{
        Email = $_.Email
        CanonicalName = $_.CanonicalName
        LastName = $_."Last Name"
        FirstName = $_."First Name"

    }

} | Select-Object LastName, Firstname, Email, CanonicalName | Sort-Object CanonicalName | Export-CSV $outpath -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what resulting CSV should look like, so this code just adds `CannonicalName` using [Calculated Properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to `Import.Csv` and saves it as `Export.Csv`.

```
$path = "C:\Scripts\Import.csv"
$outpath = "C:\Scripts\Export.csv"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Import-Csv -Path $path |
    Select-Object -Property *, @{
        n = 'CanonicalName'
        e = {(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($_.Email)))" -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName}
    } | Export-Csv -Path $outpath -NoTypeInformation
```

#### Update

This version will create a new CSV file with 3 columns: `UserExistInOu`, `Email` and `CanonicalName` if any:

```
Import-Csv -Path $path | ForEach-Object {
    $UserExistInOu = $false
    if($CanonicalName = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($_.Email)))" -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName)
    {
        $UserExistInOu = $true
    }

    New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject -Property @{
        UserExistInOu = $UserExistInOu
        Email = $_.Email
        CanonicalName = $CanonicalName
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path $outpath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You don't extract the CN from the expression E. I think you need a select -expand statement in there or use dot notation `(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($_.Email)))" -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName`. Some sort error prevention might be a good idea as well. The op had a little something in this ascpect

Comment: I was trying to output the email address and canonical name into a spreadsheet with an indicator of whether the account was listed in Active Directory or not.  My text file output had something like this:
`User does exist in OU   Joe.User@domain.com Fabrikam.com/Washington/Users/User, Joe` 
The results from this script add an extra column to my original csv which shows the Canonical name. So the appearance of this is an indicator that there is a match in the input file and in AD. I think I can technically get what I need by using this but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @YEMyslf See updated answer, is this what CSV should look like?

Comment: Yes that gets me exactly what I need. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Follow up question. I'd like to be able to use this to query child domains but I'm having trouble with the `-or` command. If I do what's listed below, I just get true/false in Cname field. Why?
`Import-Csv -Path $path | ForEach-Object {
    $UserExistInOu = $false
    if($CanonicalName = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($_.Email)))" -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName -or ($CanonicalName = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($_.Email)))" -server child.domain.com -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName))
    {
        $UserExistInOu = $true
    }`

Comment: @YEMyslf Wrap first `CanonicalName` lookup in parenthesis too: `($CanonicalName = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($_.Email)))" -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName) -or`. And in this case I'd do it this way: `$CanonicalName = 'domain.com', 'child.domain.com' | ForEach-Object {(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($_.Email)))" -Server $_ -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName} | Where-Object {$_}`. And then : `if($CanonicalName){$UserExistInOu = $true}`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. I believe you are showing tow options right? Using two comments since I won't have room for both:

Comment: From what I can tell, the only difference I see in your example is there is parenthesis after `CanonicalName.CanonicalName)` but that format isn't valid So I have:
`Import-Csv -Path $path | ForEach-Object {
    $UserExistInOu = $false
    if($CanonicalName = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($_.Email)))" -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName) -or ($CanonicalName = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($_.Email)))" -server child.domain.com -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName))
    {
        $UserExistInOu = $true
    }`

Comment: In the second example I believe you are saying to try this but I get an error that the search filter cannot be recognize -- $CanonicalName = 'child.domain.com', 'domain.com' | ForEach-Object {( ...
Here is what I'm trying-
`Import-Csv -Path $path | ForEach-Object {
    $UserExistInOu = $false
    $CanonicalName = 'domain.com', 'child.domain.com' | ForEach-Object {(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($_.Email)))" -Server $_ -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName} | Where-Object {$_}
    {if($CanonicalName)
    {$UserExistInOu = $true}
    }`

Comment: Disregard --I figured out how to do what I needed. Posting my final code up top in case it will help someone in the future.